# Build gradle script with modules on kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I want to migrate from Groovy to Kotlin DSL in my gradle build script. I have 2 scripts in the project: `build.gradle` and `publish-maven.gradle` which is attached in the first one.

For Groovy I apply the script like that:

```
apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/publish-maven.gradle"
```

For Kotlin, I found the same code will look like that:

```
apply(from = "publish-maven.gradle.kts")
```

But `publish-maven.gradle.kts` isn't attached to `build.gradle.kts`. At the top of the script the IDE constantly shows warning:

> Code insight unavailable (configuration for this script wasn't
> received during the last Gradle project import)

and Kotlin syntax isn't recognised.

I also tried

```kotlin
apply(from = "${rootProject.projectDir}/publish-maven.gradle.kts")
```

or have found other examples but non of them helped.

What do I have to do to apply this script?
Or the general question is how can I split build script into several files?

Gradle version: 6.7; JDK: 1.8; IDE: IntellijIdea

Comment: Any success? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I decided not to split build script into several files.

Comment: It's probably not supported. This seems related https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1287

Comment: Can you add the code for `build.gradle` file in which you imported the other script file?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, a fix for "Code insight unavailable" message in Intellij was to add references to my subprojects in `settings.gradle.kts` file.

I've tried to set a Gradle project with two subprojects: "app" and "core". I didn't follow the examples correctly and I didn't include references in `settings.gradle.kts`.

`settings.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "MyProject"

include("app", "core") // <-- Line added
```

After reloading the Gradle project in the IDE, everything was fine.

While I might not be answering your question specifically (I'm sorry for that), this is one of very few results for searching "Code insight unavailable" in the search engine, so I hope someone will find this answer useful.

Comment: The error "Code insight unavailable" never went away for us, after successfully migrating from Groovy to Kotlin DSL. What ended up fixing the problem was removing the reference to `mavenLocal()` (it was no longer used) in the root build.gradle.kts file.