# "Code insight unavailable" warning while using kotlin dsl

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dsl

I started to migrate groovy gradle scripts to kotlin dsl and didn't encounter any problem with build.gradle and settings.gradle files. I have several scripts that i apply in build.gradle.kts. When i change these scripts to kotlin dsl, android studio shows "Code insight unavailable (scripts configuration wasn't received.)" message and yet scripts are still working.

I have scripts directory under root project and this is how i apply in build.gradle.kts:

```
apply(from = "../scripts/ktlint.gradle.kts")
```

Example script file :

```
val ktlint by configurations.creating

tasks.register<JavaExec>("ktlint") {
  description = "Check Kotlin code style."
  main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
  classpath = ktlint
  args = listOf("src/**/*.kt")
}

tasks.register<JavaExec>("ktlintFormat") {
  description = "Fix Kotlin code style deviations."
  main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
  classpath = ktlint
  args = listOf("-F", "src/**/*.kt")
}

dependencies {
  ktlint(libs.ktlint)
}
```

I tried to move scripts directory to under app module and buildSrc but the warning didn't resolve. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, it's because my buildSrc implementation was wrong. [This topic](https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-build-logic-with-kotlin-dsl-203274f73013.) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Searching online didn't lead me to a straight answer but:

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69043719/14120486) answer

> I've tried to set a Gradle project with two subprojects: "app" and "core". I didn't follow the examples correctly and I didn't include references in **`settings.gradle.kts`**.

```
rootProject.name = "MyProject"
include("app", "core") // <-- Line added
```

So, did you correctly imported your subproject during the migration ?

Since online is really poor of information about this problem, I would go with the "old" way

`File -> Invalidate Caches -> Restart`

`Build -> Clean Project / Rebuild Project`

If nothing works, I would suggest you start again the migration guide from [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl) or from [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/migrating-gradle-build-scripts-to-kotlin-dsl-89788a4e383a). If again, nothing works, I would file a bug report and submit it to [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)

Comment: I have only app module right now and it's  included as mentioned in answer. This answer confused me because my scripts directory is not under app module. Thats whay i moved it in app module but it didn't help either.

Comment: Sorry about that but this is the only piece of information I found that could possibly fit your case.

Comment: @BerkayKireçci did you find solution?